# Don't have access with scan QR Code to Google Api

Tags: java, android, camera

I have a problem with a scanning QR Code.
One step 
First  activity show me UUID device

```
private final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "uuidValue";
private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 1;
private static int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static TextView uuidTextView;


private String uunitValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_number);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Typeface custom_fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf");

    Typeface custom_fonts2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

    TextView toolbarText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_GetNumber);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_restart);
    toolbarText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

    TextView stageOneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stageOneText);
    stageOneText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

    TextView stageTwoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stageTwoText);
    stageTwoText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

    TextView stageThreeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stageThreeText);
    stageThreeText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

    TextView generateCard = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGenerationCard);
    generateCard.setTypeface(custom_fonts);


     uuidTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uniqueNumberTextView);
    uuidTextView.setTypeface(custom_fonts2);

  //  (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ScanQrCodeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))

    if ( PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED==ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(GetNumberActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {

        uuidTextView.setText(deviceUDID(GetNumberActivity.this));
        uunitValue = deviceUDID(GetNumberActivity.this);

    }


    TextView nextButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nextButton.setTypeface(custom_fonts);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(GetNumberActivity.this, ScanQrCodeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, uunitValue);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




public String deviceUDID(Context ctx) {
    final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
    tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
    tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
    String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
    Log.d("Device Id", deviceId);

    String newUUID = deviceId.replace("-", "");
    String code = newUUID.substring(23, 31);
    return code;
}

//show Alter Dialog
public void showAlterDialog(String title, String message) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(GetNumberActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    alert.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Second Activity Scan QR Code

```
public class ScanQrCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "hotpValume";
private static final String TAG = "Wartość błędna QR Codu";

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

SurfaceView cameraPreview;
private String hotpValue;
private String sms;
private String barcodeValue;
private String uuidDevice;
private TextView text;

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_qr_code);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_restart);
    Typeface custom_fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    TextView title_app = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_application_scan);
    title_app.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

    TextView stageOneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stageTwoText);
    stageOneText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

    TextView stageTwoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stageTwoText);
    stageTwoText.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScan);
    text.setTypeface(custom_fonts);

    cameraPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    createCameraSource();

    sms = getIntent().getStringExtra("smsCode");

    uuidDevice = getIntent().getStringExtra("uuidValue");

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

private void createCameraSource() {

    final BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).build();
    final CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600, 1200)
            .build();

    cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ScanQrCodeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    Log.w(TAG, e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                showAlterDialog("Brak uprawnień ", "Brak uprawnień do camery. Spróbuj jeszcze raz.");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            cameraSource.stop();
        }
    });
    barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
        @Override
        public void release() {

        }

        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (barcodes.size() != 0) text.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    v.vibrate(500);
                    String barcodeString = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;

                }
            });

        }
    });

}
```

Now, I checked with my phone on Nexus 5 and Asus appears after dialogue not access of the Camera. As tests Apke on tablet Samsung Tab 4 all view appears DIY camera can scan the QR Code. I do not know what has been badly implemented.

Comment: Have you added run time permission for Camera?